# django-hstore DictionaryField returns string rather than a dictionary

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-hstore

I am running through a little strange behaviour on my test cases with django-hstore.

I am working on a django rest framework project and models may look like below

## models

```
from django_hstore.hstore import DictionaryField

class Config(models.Model):

    data = data = DictionaryField(db_index=True)
```

And i am trying to test a scenario based on Config model and does something like this

## Tests

```
class ConfigTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        Config.objects.create(data={'pagination_number': '50'})

    def test_config_data(self):
        # Below code is getting failed
        Config.objects.first().data.get('pagination_number')
```

When i do Config.objects.first().data

i am getting '"pagination_number"=>"50"'

i was expecting {'pagination_number': 50}

This is happening only when i run tests

When i am performing create operation on my command shell manually everything works fine and code also executes fine

I am using django-hstore 1.2.1

PostgreSQL 9.4.4

I am unable to figure out the reason for this

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find the solution for your problem, I ended up finding this increasing discussion a while ago, in [django-hstore group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-hstore/sI_3vdrfeP0)

**Andrey Antukh** reproduced the error.

```
================================================== ====================
FAIL: test_properties_hstore (tests.django_hstore_tests.tests.HstoreTest)
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/niwi/devel/django-hstore/tests/django_hstore_tests/tests.py", line 471, in test_properties_hstore
    self.assertEqual (type (instance.data), HStoreDict) # TEST FAILS HERE
AssertionError: <class 'str'> = <class 'django_hstore.fields.HStoreDict'>
```

if you read the [documentation](http://djangonauts.github.io/django-hstore/#_limitations) of hstore:

> 1.4. Limitations PostgreSQL's implementation of hstore has no concept of type; it stores the mapping of string keys to string values. Values
>   ​​are strings stored in the database Regarding of Their original type.
>   This limitation can be Overcome by using either the schema mode since
>   version 1.3.0 or by using the serialized dictionary field since
>   version 1.3.6 of django_hstore.

Update the version of django-hstore. this *maybe* solve the problem.